# Summing split dataframe columns in an iterative process

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a dataframe "fpd" which is split on unique values in column `['View']` using

```
bookuniques = fpd['View'].unique()

fpdict = {elem: pd.DataFrame for elem in bookuniques}

for key in fpdict.keys():
    fpdict[key] = fpd[:][fpd['View'] == key]
```

The dataframe looks like:

```
    Product PG Location Row Group   Ph DD                   Pd TC   Variance    
    C4      CL          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        200     200     
            PU          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        400     400
            MR          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        600     600 
            NP          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        200     200
            PR          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        400     400 
            PS          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        600     600 
            PW          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        200     200
```

I am attempting to append a sum row for each of these dataframes individually. I have tried including the process on the output to excel using

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('check2.xlsx') as writer:
    for key in fpdict.keys():
        fpdict[key].drop(['View'], axis = 1) 
        fpdict[key].append(fpdict[key].sum(numeric_only = True), ignore_index=True)
        temp = fpdict[key]
        temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = key)
```

Unfortunately, doing so **removes** the index columns `[['Product'],['PG'],['Location']]`

I would like the output to be

```
        Product PG Location Row Group   Ph DD                   Pd TC   Variance    
        C4      CL          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        200     200     
                PU          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        400     400
                MR          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        600     600 
                NP          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        200     200
                PR          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        400     400 
                PS          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        600     600 
                PW          01.1 OI     OpeningInventory        200     200
                TOTAL                                           2600    2600
```

Comment: Have you tried `groupby`: `fpd.groupby('View').sum()`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I haven't yet - would I need to remove my hierarchical indexing to use that?

Comment: @SergeBallesta update - tried it and nothing happened

Comment: Without a [mcve] we won't be able to help...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have reproduced output and documented desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the assumptions I have to do because this is not clearly stated in the question:

- the dataframe has a multi-index on columns Product, PG, Location
- the new row will have PG=Total and all other non numeric fields set to an empty string
- fpdict[key] will have `View` column removed

You have to change your code to:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('check2.xlsx') as writer:
    for key in fpdict.keys():
        temp = fpdict[key].drop(['View'], axis = 1).reset_index()
        temp.append(fpdict[key].sum(numeric_only = True), ignore_index=True) # add sum row
        temp.iloc[-1] = temp.iloc[-1].fillna(' ')      # replace NaNs with ''
        temp.iloc[-1, 1] = 'TOTAL'
        fpdict[key] = temp.set_index(['Product', 'PG', 'Location'])
        temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = key)
```

Comment: I will give this a go - as for the question, I would love to know how I can make it better.

I'm not sure how to highlight the individual words to visually identify them as the index - I tried with the formatting but it got messy. Is there a resource for formatting dataframes?

I'll make sure to specify the desired output for the other fields next time - I thought it was clear from the question but I understand why it would be confusing. 

I also realize I left out the view column - apologies.

Comment: The only edit I had to make is to preface the temp.append line with temp =. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Additionally, I had to change temp.to_excel to fpdict[key] to excel, otherwise the output didn't retain the indexed format